# Regex to get string within double quote and inside bracket

Tags: java, regex

This is my string test :

```
[{"orange":["1.00","5"]},{"apple":["2.00","5"]},{"grapes":["3.00","5"]}]
```

how can i get the string with in double quotes,splitted by every two brackets`{}`, i want to have output like this :
1st loop :

```
orange
1.00
5
```

2nd loop :

```
apple
2.00
5
```

3rd loop :

```
grapes
3.00
5


"\\{(.*?)\\}"
```

this regex gets data inside bracket, and also i want to get from that match, all string between double quotes.

Any help is so much appreciated.

Comment: If the input format remains the same, you can try JSON parser.

Comment: @srkavin, can you give me example on that

Comment: @Niang you can use Jackson which is a popular JSON parser. http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonInFiveMinutes

Answer (score 1):

Use this regex

```
\{"([^"]+)":\["([^"]+)","([^"]+)
```

And retrieve the tokens from Groups 1, 2 and 3.

In **[the Regex Demo](http://regex101.com/r/dU5lQ3/9)**, look at the Groups in the **right pane**.

**In Java:**

```
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("\\{\"([^\"]+)\":\\[\"([^\"]+)\",\"([^\"]+)");
Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(subjectString);
while (regexMatcher.find()) {
        System.out.println( regexMatcher.group(1) );
        System.out.println( regexMatcher.group(2) );
        System.out.println( regexMatcher.group(3) );
    }
```

Comment: hi,how can i print  `regexMatcher.group(1)`

Comment: sir i do have a question,it seems redundancy to me this code `\"([^\"]+` and also im concern because `,{"grapes":[item on this changes on size]}`