# Regex - Match quotes between brackets

Tags: .net, regex

Example string:

> cov('Age', ['5','7','9'])

I have this RegEx that matches the values inside quotes:

```
(["'])(?:(?=(\\?))\2.)*?\1
```

I´m trying to modifiy it to only return the quotes inside the square brackets from the example string using lookahead/lookbehind:

```
(?<=\[)(["'])(?:(?=(\\?))\2.)*?\1(?=\])
```

But it matches everything inside the square brackets.

How can i match only the quotes without the commas like in the first regex, but inside the square brackets?

Edit.

The language is .NET.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regex to get string within double quote and inside bracket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25048177/regex-to-get-string-within-double-quote-and-inside-bracket)

Comment: Which language or regex engine? In PCRE, The fourth bird's answer is a good one, in other regex flavours it might not work.

Comment: Edited: language is .NET.

Comment: What are you doing? Removing all `'` and `"` inside `[....]`? Is it C#? Do you have access to the code? It may turn out much simpler. You have `cov('Age', ['5','7','9'])`, what is exact expected result and its type?

Comment: Yes, It is my code. C#. I receive this string from a get request and must dynamically convert the values inside the brackets to an .Net array.

Comment: I do not think you need that complex regex here. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58231627/3832970).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option if supported is to make use of the `\G` anchor and a capturing group:

```
(?:\[|\G(?!^))('[^']+'),?(?=[^\]]*\])
```

In parts

- `(?:` Non capturing group
- `\[` Match opening `[`

  - `|` Or
  - `\G(?!^)` Assert position at the end of the previous match
- `)` Close non capturing group
- `(` Capture group 1

  - `'[^']+'` Match `'`, 1+ times any char except `'`, then match `'` again
- `)` Close group 1
- `,?` Match an optional `,`
- `(?=[^\]]*\])` Positive lookahead, assert a closing `]`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/MwMzBo/1) | [C# demo](https://ideone.com/stiEpn)

For example

```
string pattern = @"(?:\[|\G(?!^))('[^']+'),?(?=[^\]]*\])";
string input = @"cov('Age', ['5','7','9'])";

var results = Regex.Matches(input, pattern)
.Cast<Match>()
.Select(m => m.Groups[1].Value)
.ToArray();

foreach(string result in results)
{
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

Output

```
'5'
'7'
'9'
```

Comment: It works perfectly, thanks!! Just one question: there's a way that i can use the backslash '\'  to to escape the quote characters? Suppose i want to write a quote inside one of the array's elements: ['5', '5\''], this way the backslash doesnt break the regex. the first regex in my example does that "(?=(\\?))" by i'm not sure how to apply it to your example.

Answer (score 3):

You haven't specified a language or regex engine so answering your question is difficult. The fourth bird's answer works for specific regex engines (e.g. PCRE) but not others. Another alternative exists in .NET as well.

For [.net](/questions/tagged/.net) you can use the following since this regex engine collects all captures into a [`CaptureCollection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.capturecollection?view=netframework-4.8):

[See regex in use here](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5c%5b%28%27%5b%5e%27%5d*%27%5b%2c%5c%5d%5d%29%2b%28%3f%3c%3d%5d%29&i=cov%28%27Age%27%2c+%5b%275%27%2c%277%27%2c%279%27%5d%29)

```
\[('[^']*'[,\]])+(?<=])
```

---

For most other languages (not covered by this answer or [@Thefourthbird's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58174739/3600709)), you'll want to do this in two steps:

- Get all strings that match `\[([^[\]]*)]` (you want the value of group 1)
- Match all occurrences of `'([^']*)'` (you want the value of group 1 for contents)

Answer (score 1):

You do not seem to need any complex regex: grab a string between two square brackets and split the captured contents with single quote or comma, or plainly match what you need there.

Given

```
var text = "cov('Age', ['5','7','9'])";
```

The approaches can be:

```
// Split captured text with ' and , 
var results = Regex.Matches(text, @"\[([^][]+)]")
        .Cast<Match>()
        .Select(x => x.Groups[1].Value.Split('\'', ',').Where(c => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(c)));
```

Or, match the strings between brackets and then extract all 1+ digit chunks from it:

```
var results1 = Regex.Matches(text, @"\[([^][]+)]")
        .Cast<Match>()
        .Select(x => Regex.Matches(x.Groups[1].Value, @"\d+"));
```

Or, just extract all numbers inside `[...]`:

```
var results = Regex.Matches(text, @"(?<=\[[^][]*)\d+(?=[^][]*])").Cast<Match>().Select(x => x.Value);
```

Here, the [regex matches](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3C%3D%5C%5B%5B%5E%5D%5B%5D*%29%5Cd%2B%28%3F%3D%5B%5E%5D%5B%5D*%5D%29&i=cov%28%27Age%27%2C%20%5B%275%27%2C%277%27%2C%279%27%5D%29)

- `(?<=\[[^][]*)` - position that is preceded with `[` and any amount of chars other than `[` and `]`
- `\d+` - 1+ digits
- `(?=[^][]*])` - position followed with any 0+ chars other than `[` and `]` and then `]`.

See [**the online C# demo**](http://ideone.com/ebpOUL).

It gets a bit more complex [to extract any number](https://www.regular-expressions.info/floatingpoint.html), replace `\d+` with `[-+]?\d*\.?\d+([eE][-+]?\d+)?`